# xcode can not recognize iPad

Tags: iphone

I just upgraded XCode to 3.2.6

but Organizer said that XCode can not find the software image to install this version
ipad:ios 4.3.3(8j3)

Welcome any comment

Comment: What is your current iOS version on your iPad?  I don't believe it is possible to downgrade an iOS on a device, but if its < 4.3.3 then this is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah but Apple isn't going to let you install this version anyway.. You got to stay in the current version or if you need to perform a restore, go to iOS 5 and update Xcode to 4.2